# Remove data from an array comparing it to an other array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to compare the items in "item" array and the copyofOpList array to retrieve the data occurrences in copyofOpList

this is my try:

```
var _deleteUsedElement1 = function(item) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < item.length-1; i++){      
                          for (var j = 0; j< $scope.copyofOpList.length-1; j++){
                        if (item[i].operationCode == $scope.copyofOpList[j].code) {
                        $scope.copyofOpList.splice(j, 1);

                        } } } };

 $scope.compareArrays = function() {
     ...Get data from web Service
    _deleteUsedElement1(item);
  }
```

the copyofOpList array has 14 elements,and the item array has 2 array
but my code deletes only one occurrence (the first),so please how can I correct my code,to retrieve any occurances in the copyofOpList array comparing to the item array
thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try to avoid looping inside a loop - that's neither a very elegant nor a very efficient way to get the result you want.

Here's something more elegant and most likely more efficient:

```
var item = [1,2], copyofOpList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

var _deleteUsedElement1 = function(item, copyofOpList) {
    return copyofOpList.filter(function(listItem) {
     return item.indexOf(listItem) === -1;
   });
  };

    copyofOpList = _deleteUsedElement1(item, copyofOpList);
    console.log(copyofOpList);
    //prints [3,4,5,6,7]
}
```

And since I just noticed that you're comparing object properties, here's a version that filters on matching object properties:

```
var item = [{opCode:1},{opCode:2}],
    copyofOpList = [{opCode:1},{opCode:2},{opCode:3},{opCode:4},{opCode:5},{opCode:6},{opCode:7}];

var _deleteUsedElement1 = function(item, copyofOpList) {
      var iOpCodes = item.map(function (i) {return i.opCode;});
      return copyofOpList.filter(function(listItem) {
        return iOpCodes.indexOf(listItem.opCode) === -1;
      });
    };

copyofOpList = _deleteUsedElement1(item, copyofOpList);
console.log(copyofOpList);
//prints [{opCode:3},{opCode:4},{opCode:5},{opCode:6},{opCode:7}]
```

Another benefit of doing it in this manner is that you avoid modifying your arrays while you're still operating on them, a positive effect that both JonSG and Furhan S. mentioned in their answers.

Comment: Thats very elegant and concise. Though I would like to point out that its still looping inside a loop, because indexOf() is a loop in itself :)

Comment: With your edits, this covers my answer so I will remove it.

Comment: @FurhanS. Thanks, and you're right about the loop. I guess nested `for`s just hurt my eyes. There's also the question of whether the `for` is more or less efficient than the `indexOf()`. It seems that `for` was more efficient in the early days of `indexOf()`, but it also seems that the performance of `indexOf()` has improved and the situation may have even reversed in the interim (based on some quick googling, so don't hold me to it).

Comment: @JonSG I thought your answer added to the discussion. I edited mine just now to mention the benefit of not altering the arrays while operating on them, which you also pointed out in your excellent answer.

Answer (score 2):

Splicing will change your array. Use a temporary buffer array for new values like this:

```
var _deleteUsedElement1 = function(item) {
    var _temp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.copyofOpList.length-1; i++){      
        for (var j = 0; j< item.length-1; j++){
           if ($scope.copyofOpList[i].code != item[j].operationCode) {
               _temp.push($scope.copyofOpList[j]);
           } 
        } 
    } 
    $scope.copyofOpList = _temp;
};
```

Comment: Have you tested this? I don't think it does what the requester needs.

Comment: @Tex you were right. Didn't test the first time, hope the edited code does what is required as per my understanding. Thnx for pointing out.

Comment: Hey, check out filter(), it kind of does what you are doing with _temp